# Axios request returns error Request failed with status code 408 to localhost but works in remote server

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios, nestjs

I'm developing a script with NodeJs + Typescript in order to upload images and information to a Nestjs app also developed by me. I'm using Axios for the http requests, when I run the script to localhost inmediately fails the request and returns AxiosError: Request failed with status code 408. I have the Nestjs server deployed in a local company server. When I run the script pointing to that server it works fine. The only difference between the nestjs app running in my local machine and the one in the server is that in my local machine its running with nodejs in port 3000 and in the server its running with nodejs but behind a reverse-proxy using nginx.

When I tried the request using Postman or Vscode extension Thunder Client it works fine to my local Nestjs app. This is my code and the error response:

```
    const options = {
          headers: {
            Accept: "*/*",
            "User-Agent": "Thunder Client (https://www.thunderclient.com)",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            // "api-key": apiKey,
          },
        };
    const url = "http://localhost:3000/image/uploadImgBlob";
    
    const data  = {
        dateImage: "some info ",
        region: "some info ",
        timeImage: "some info ",
        typeImage: "some info ",
    }
    
    try {
      await axios.post(url, data, options)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      
    }
```

Using localhost it returns this error immediately, never reaches to the server:

```
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 408
    at settle (/media/datos/Desarrollo/Projects/almacena-mapa-3.0/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:1909:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/media/datos/Desarrollo/Projects/almacena-mapa-3.0/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:2989:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
```

Using

```
const url = http://opmet.maq.server.com // my deployed server address example
```

it works fine. Also using postman or another http client form my local machine to localhost app works ok.

Can anyone help me with this issue.
Thanks in adv.
Regards Lazaro